# Allow for IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY for one route using regexp in Symfony security

Tags: regex, symfony, security, configuration, yaml

I'm working on a Symfony 3.4 application and I'm trying to configure properly my security.yml to block all the website for unlogged users exept for :

```
/login
/register
/resseting
```

And one special shared page (I'm going to give more info).

Here is my security.yml access_control :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I'm using the _locale in my "in app" routes as followed in my `routing.yml`:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Here is (a part of) the result of the command `bin/console debug:router` :

[image]
...
[image]

The route I need to allow for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` is `customer_view` (path: /{_locale}/q/{token})

I already tried many different paths as :

```
- { path: ^/q/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/%locale%/q/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/q/[a-z]+, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- etc .........
```

I don't find good information on the web, neither on the symfony doc ...
Any help ?

**-EDIT-**

Also, I'm affraid that i may open the route for evryone using `^/q/` because "q" could be interpreted as the locale ? How could I do it without compromising the security of my application ?

Comment: Just one question, why the locale is the first part of the URI ? It is difficult to restrict from `access_control` because of that.

Comment: why do you need to use regex? What is the browser path for customer_view url?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex for whole path, I would try something as following.

```
- { path: ^/(%locales_string%)/customer_view, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
```